# Tiny MCE Default Content

Tags: tinymce, django-tinymce

I want to load TinyMCe with default content as below when loaded .

```
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I have set cleanup : false . Still it wraps html with `<p></p>` and removes my code .

Any solution to this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved . Just had to enable full html plugin.